# Plots.jl: remove series legend, keep color bar

Tags: julia, plots.jl

Using Plots.jl I can make a scatter plot from two vectors with color set by another vector as follows:

```
using Plots
scatter([1,3,5,7], [2,4,6,10], marker_z = [1,1,2,3])
```

[image]

There is both a legend for the series, and there is a color bar.

If I set `legend = false` both are removed:

```
scatter([1,3,5,7], [2,4,6,10], marker_z = [1,1,2,3], legend = false)
```

[image: :]

I would like to remove the legend for the series (the "y1" in a box), and keep the color bar. Does anyone know how to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Derp, figured it out.

```
scatter([1,3,5,7], [2,4,6,10], marker_z = [1,1,2,3], legend = false, 
        colorbar = true)
```

[image]